# Query string appended to URL when 2 rewriterules are applied

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am rewriting a site from classic asp to php. Not all the new file names will match so I can't simply rewrite .asp to .php. The php site will be using more readable URLs. I am having a problem with the following scenario:

The old page

old-profile.asp?company=ABC+Limited

needs to be redirected to

/profiles/ABC+Limited

The following rewritecond/rewriterule works perfectly when it is the only rule applied:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^company=([^/]+)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^old-profile\.asp$ /profiles/%1? [R=301,L]
```

so if I enter /old-profile.asp?company=ABC+Limited the result is /profiles/ABC+Limited

However, later in the .htaccess file I need to use the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/]+)$ /new-profile.php?company=$1
```

This also works perfectly for pages on the new site i.e. the URL /profiles/ABC+Limited will display the page at /new-profile.php?company=ABC+Limited

This all sounds ok but the problem is these 2 rules are not working in conjunction with one another. The problem is that the result of the following URL:

/old-profile.asp?company=ABC+Limited

is:

/profiles/ABC+Limited?company=ABC+Limited

I do not want the ?company+ABC+Limited on the end of this new URL. In the first rewriterule I have added the trailing ? and this rule works ok if I comment out the second rule, but when both rules are applied the querystring appears.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

**UPDATE** With help from @anubhava and @Samurai8 I have discovered the cause of this problem. The old site forces www. at the beginning of URLs and new site forces no www. at the beginning of URL.

The www. to no www. rule was after all the other rules in my htaccess file and was causing this problem. I moved it to the beginning of the file and it is all working ok.

Comment: Is it possible to use the second rule before the first? Or as workaround: change rule 1 to 'tmp-profiles ...' as result and add a third rule at the end which converts tmp-profile to profile.

Comment: Hi @JörgMäder, I have tried changing the order and it makes no difference. The first rule is a 301 so the rules should not be run on the same request and therefore should not interfere - but something is up. I will have a go at changing the rule and adding another...

Comment: I would also like to 301 from the old URL to the new "pretty" URL to take the search engine credit with us, so not sure how that would work if I put another rule in?

Comment: In response to changing rule one to tmp-page and adding a third rule, this had the same result. I suppose I could actually create a new page and redirect from the page but this would be a bit messy and I think would prevent carrying our search credit from the old page to the new?

Comment: First, change `[R=301` to `[R=302`. Testing with permanent redirects is a horror. It might actually be the reason this is happening in the first place. Then clear your browser cache, open the developer console (right-click>inspect element), go to the network tab and enter `old-profile.asp?company=Pretty+Unicorn` in your url bar. Look at the network tab and observe exactly what is happening. What url redirects to what page? This will give you a hint of what is actually happening inside. Add the `[L]` flag to every rule if it hasn't got that flag yet.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^company=([^&]+)    [NC]
RewriteRule ^old-profile\.asp$ /profiles/%1? [R=301,L,NE,NC]

RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/]+)/?$ new-profile.php?company=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then make sure you test this in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava - I can see that this is your area of expertise. I tried your code in my .htaccess and I got the same result. So I then tried in a completely new htaccess file containing only these rules and it worked, but so did my old code, so there must be another issue in my htaccess.

Comment: If you have other rules as well then make sure these rules are placed before them. If that doesn't work somehow, try posting your entire .htaccess in question so that I can investigate and suggest some remedy.

Comment: I have edited the question. The problem seems to be that I was forcing no www. before all URLs and this rule was after the others. I have put this rule before them and it seems to have worked. Does this sound like a reasonable explanation and solution to you?

Comment: Yes that sounds right. `www. to no www` rule must be placed before above rules.